# Сравнение дат добавления данных в sqlite3

Tags: дата, sqlite3, сравнение

Подскажите, как в sqlite можно решить такую задачу:

Есть такой  столбец в БД:

```
12  created_at  DATETIME    No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   No
```

В него записываются дата-время добавления данных в БД.

Требуется выбрать в запросе только те строки из базы, для которых значение поля created_at - это время ПОСЛЕДНЕГО добавления данных.

Как мне нужно написать условие WERE created_at... ?

Данные обновляются (добавляются к уже существующим в БД) несколько раз в день. И мне при каждом обновлении нужно отредактировать только вновь полученные данные.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable GROUP BY key_field ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Здесь `key_field` -  поле, по которому однозначно определяется, какие данные добавлялись.

Если же Ваш вопрос состоит в том, чтобы просто отобразить только последние N записей, которые добавлены в БД, то нужно использовать `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT * FROM ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10
```

Выведет последние 10 записей из БД.

Если же нужно, чтобы получить записи после некоторой даты (например, последнего обновления БД).

```
SELECT * FROM ORDER BY created_at >= ?
```

Вместо ? подставляете дату последнего обновления БД. Но, ***здесь нужно быть очень аккуратным, т.к. в SQLite очень много зависит от того, как хранится дата***.

Comment: Только по created_at и определяется. Я могу использовать его в запросе дважды? SELECT * FROM MyTable GROUP BY created_at ORDER BY created_at DESC

Comment: Нет. Если две и более записей  относятся к одной и той же сущности БД, нужен отдельный ключ.

Comment: Если Вам просто нужно вывести последние N записей из БД, используйте `LIMIT`.

Comment: этих записей может быть 10, а может быть 200. Мне нужны все последние, независимо от количества

Comment: @КвартирыПетербург, Вы пожалуйста уточните, что Вы имеете в виду в качестве "последних". Каковы критерии того, что они последние? Это какое-то количество самых новых записей, записи сделанные не ранее какой-то даты (например, даты последнего обновления БД), ... ? Простите, но действительно трудно понять, что Вам нужно.

Comment: Последние записи - это внесенные при последнем обновлении БД. Их количество может быть любым. База обновляется несколько раз в день по расписанию. Вот, последняя группа записей и должна быть выбрана